# Best way to show fields not in the model in a One2many widget ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to show a column on a form but the field I want to access is not store in the model.
I've the following models:

```
class Class1(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.class1'

    field1 = fields.Integer(string='field1')
    field2 = fields.Integer(string='field2')


class Class2(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.class1'

    field1 = fields.Integer(string='field1')
    field2 = fields.Integer(string='field2')
    class3_ids = fields.One2many('module.class3', 'class2_id', string="class2")

class Class3(models.Model):
    _name='module.class3'

    class2_id = fields.Many2one('module.class2')
    class1_id = fields.Many2one('module.class1')
    field1 = fields.Float(string='field1')
```

I'm the form I want to display in class1 form the class2 records but show some class1 fields somethin like this:

```
<record id="module_class1_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">module_class1: form</field>
    <field name="model">module.class1</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="number"/>
                    <field name="class3_ids" nolabel="1">
                        <tree string="class3" editable="bottom" nolabel="1">
                          <field name="field1"/>
                          <field name="class1_id"/>
                          <field name="class1_id.SOMEFIELD"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

The code work fine, except for the part of                            i want to access and show data from class1
I was thinking to use computed fields but is a more pythonic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `related` field. In your model:

```
class Class3(models.Model):
    _name='module.class3'

    class2_id = fields.Many2one('module.class2')
    class1_id = fields.Many2one('module.class1')
    field1 = fields.Float(string='field1')
    class1field1 = fields.Integer(related='class1_id.field1')
```

And in a view:

```
<field name="class1field1"/>
```